# How to push a new object to an array of objects using a from input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object, input

As the title says, i have an array of objects:

```
let bookObjects = [
        {
            title: "Defender With A Goal",
        },
        {
            title: "Pirate Of The End",
        },
        {
            title: "Kings Of Rainbows",
        },
        {
            title: "Traitors Of The Forsaken",
        },
        {
            title: "Enemies And Invaders",
        },
    ];
```

And i have a form:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    Add new element to the table: <br>
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="addNewObjet(this.form)">
    </p>
</form>
```

And a function that should add a new object:

```
addNewObjet = (form) => {
        let newTitle = form.inputbox.value; //inputbox is the name of the input

        bookObjects.push(
            {
                title: newTitle,
            },
        );
    }
```

If i try to push into bookObjects without the input it does work, but with the form it doesn't.

Comment: should it really be onClick instead of onclick?

Comment: working as expected [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6h1fwkc/). You'll need to show how your code is organized for more concrete help. (where do you declare `bookObjects` in relation to your handler etc.)

Comment: @link2name Attribute names are case-insensitive, but it _should_ be neither. The code should [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let bookObjects = [
        {
            title: "Defender With A Goal",
        },
        {
            title: "Pirate Of The End",
        },
        {
            title: "Kings Of Rainbows",
        },
        {
            title: "Traitors Of The Forsaken",
        },
        {
            title: "Enemies And Invaders",
        },
    ];
    
    addNewObjet = (form) => {
        let newTitle = form.inputbox.value; //inputbox is the name of the input

        bookObjects.push(
            {
                title: newTitle,
            },
        );
        
      var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
      table.innerHTML = "";
      
      bookObjects.forEach(b => {
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

       
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

       
      cell1.innerHTML = b.title;
      })

     
      
   
    }
        
      var table = document.getElementById("tbl");

     
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

       
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

       
      cell1.innerHTML = newTitle;
   
    }
```

This puts the input into a table and this seems to work.

Comment: just flag to close for details or not reproducible